# Javascript Reg Pack Crusher doesn't crush Audiocontext

Tags: javascript, webkitaudiocontext, audiocontext

I want to crush this Javascript code:

```
var ac = new AudioContext; //works fine without this line
var oscillator = ac.createOscillator(); 
var analyser = ac.createAnalyser();
var gain = ac.createGain();`
```

with this crusher:

http://siorki.github.io/regPack.html

It works fine for many codes but it won't crush the AudioContext variable. Without the first line it works fine.

The Javascript Console shows following error:

```
ReferenceError: varsNotReassigned is not defined
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or recommend another crusher?

Answer (score 0):

Curiously if you change your code to :

```
var adc = new AudioContext;
var oscillator = ac.createOscillator(); 
var analyser = ac.createAnalyser();
var gain = ac.createGain();
```

It crushes fine. It looks like `ac` might be a reserved term for this crusher.